# How to check sign of one value with in the range [a b]

Tags: matlab, math

I want to check sign of one value within the range by the following rule:

```
x=1 if x within the [a,b]
x=-1 otherwise
```

So I implemented by matlab code:

```
 (sign(x-a)+sign(b-x))./2
```

But my function is not correct. How to make correctly function of my problem?Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `sign(x-a)*sign(b-x)` ?

Comment: Yes. It is that my need. Thank you so much